# The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, system.net.httpwebrequest

I'm doing an integration with the Itaú bank api to generate slips.
This integration required the sending of a digital certificate.

My application is hosted on Azure.

When I run the application locally the connection happens successfully, however when I upload to the server it returns the error below.

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized - System.Net.WebException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030D): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

```
public async Task<AuthTokenItau> AutenticarItauJwt()
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://sts.itau.com.br/api/oauth/token");
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";

            var dataBody = "grant_type=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("client_credentials");
            dataBody += "&client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX");
            dataBody += "&client_secret=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX");

            var body = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataBody);
            request.ContentLength = body.Length;

            string response = "";
            Stream myWriter = null;

            try
            {

                var caminhoCertificado = $@"{_webHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath}\App_Data\Certificado\certifica_digital.pfx";
                var senhaCertificado = @"senhaZZZZ";

                X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(caminhoCertificado, senhaCertificado, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
                request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

                RegistraLog.Log($"Certificado -{certificate.ToString()}");

                myWriter = request.GetRequestStream();
                myWriter.Write(body, 0, body.Length);

                var requestResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                RegistraLog.Log($"Response : {requestResponse.Headers.AllKeys} - {dataBody.ToString()}");

                response = new StreamReader(requestResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                RegistraLog.Log($"Response -{response.ToString()}");

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthTokenItau>(response); ;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RegistraLog.Log($"Erro ao solicitar o token.\r\nDetalhe: {ex.Message} - {ex.ToString()}");

                throw new Exception("Erro ao solicitar o token.\r\nDetalhe: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (myWriter != null)
                    myWriter.Close();
            }
        }
```

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized - System.Net.WebException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030D): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCHANNEL_CRED scc)
at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCHANNEL_CRED secureCredential)
at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(X509Certificate certificate, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer)
at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at EscolaPro.ControleBoleto.AuthItauService.AutenticarItauJwt() in D:\GlobalManage\Repositorio\globalmanage\global-manage-api-web\EscolaPro.ControleBoleto\AuthItauService.cs:line 58